# Expressing permutations as products of transpositions and identifying parity

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

1. $(156)(234)= (16)(15)(24)(23)$ Even
2. $(17254)(1423)(154632)= (12)(13)(16)(14)(15)(13)(12)(14)(14)(15)(12)(17)$ Even

How is parity determined? Is it simply even when the # of transpositions is even and odd when the # of transpositions is odd?

I'm able to compute transpositions when the permutations are disjoint but otherwise run into problems. Any insight on this?

Comment: Yes, the parity of a permutation is its number of transpositions.

Comment: Do you compose cycles left-to-right or right-to-left? Meaning: Do you consider $(12)(13)$ to be equal to $(132)$ or $(123)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Contemporary Abstract Algebra", by [Dr. Joseph Gallian](http://www.d.umn.edu/~jgallian), describes an even permutation as: *A permutation that can be expressed as a product of an even number of 2-cycles is called an even permutation.*

**Note:** In the examples below, I will compose cycles from right-to-left.

The definition implies that in your first example: $(156)(234)$ is even.
$$(156)(234)=(16)(15)(24)(23)$$
We can easily verify that. Start with $1$ and see how that is transformed. In the far right cycle, there is no $1$, so it maps to itself. Likewise in the next cycle (second to end). In the third cycle, $1 \mapsto 5$. Move to the fourth cycle. Now, there is no $5$, so it maps to itself. Thus, the start of the permutation looks like: $(15...)$. So now we consider how $5$ maps. Following the same procedure, $5 \mapsto 6$, and then $6 \mapsto 1$. Since we have returned to our starting number, we "close" the cycle. That is, the cycle now is: $(156)$. Starting with the next number not in the previous cycle, which is $2$, we get $2 \mapsto 3$, $3 \mapsto 4$, and $4 \mapsto 2$. So, the final cycle is: $(156)(234)$, which is the same as the starting one. Thus, $(156)(234) = (16)(15)(24)(23)$. Because there is an even number of 2-cycles (four), the permutation is even.

For the second example it's a little more difficult, but not impossible. We just start by following the same approach as above. Start with $1$, it maps to $5$ in the first cycle (far right). Then the $5$ maps to itself in the second. And finally, $5$ maps to $4$ in the last cycle. So, $1 \mapsto 4$. Continuing this, we obtain:
$$(17254)(1423)(154632) = (14672)(3)(5)$$
By converting to disjoint cycles, it is now much easier transform to 2-cycles.
$$(14672)(3)(5) = (12)(17)(16)(14)(13)(31)(15)(51)$$
[Note: A 1-cycle (identity for an element) can be expressed as the product of two 2-cycles by selecting one element (must be different) and creating the two 2-cycles. $(x) = (xy)(yx)$]

There are eight 2-cycles, so the above permutation is even.

---

**atherton**: Your product of 2-cycles for the second example is not correct.

**Working right-to-left:**
$$(17254)(1423)(154632) = (14672)(3)(5)$$
$$(12)(13)(16)(14)(15)(13)(12)(14)(14)(15)(12)(17) = (1724635)$$
$$(14672)(3)(5) \ne (1724635)$$

**Working left-to-right:**
$$(17254)(1423)(154632) = (1724635)$$
$$(12)(13)(16)(14)(15)(13)(12)(14)(14)(15)(12)(17) = (15364271)$$
$$(1724635) \ne (15364271)$$

Notice that working right-to-left on the product of 2-cycles is the same as working left-to-right of the original product. That - to my knowledge - is just a weird coincidence. Also, it is not valid to switch the order you compose mid-problem.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than working with decompositions into transpositions, it is faster to count the number of inversions of that permutation. This means the numbers of pairs of numbers $(i,j)$ from that permutation such that $i>j$. If this number is odd, then the permutation is odd; and even for even. An example, to clarify: for $(17254)$ the inversions are: $(72), (75), (74), (54)$ - 4 of them. This one is even. For $(1423)$ we have $(42), (43)$ - again even. Finally, for $(154632)$ we get $(54), (53), (52), (43), (42), (63), (62), (32)$ - 8 inversions, even again. So their product is also even.

Comment: Ok that makes sense for finding parity. But is my transposition correct for $(17254)(1423)(154632)$?

Comment: The only verification strategy that comes to mind is direct computation - but you can do this too, I guess.